# My loopback model-relation is not working

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

As I created my user model on top of User-built in model and created a new model library. But if I'm trying to make a relationship its giving the error "unauthorized".

Here are my files:

user.json

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "phone": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "library": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Library",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and my library.json

```
{
  "name": "Library",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "category": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bookTitle": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "author": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "index": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

As you could see that foreign key is empty what exactly it means I don't know why we need to left empty that and user login is working fine. It returns me the access token which I'm setting at the top right.

I didn't find the appropriate answer as I'm saving my database to MongoDB.

Comment: Which HTTP request are you making ?

Comment: it's a simple http call,pointing locally

Comment: Which HTTP call, to which URL ? Without this information it is impossible to answer your question. And by the way, the answer you marked valid is not solving anything, because it just sets the exact same config than default config.

Answer (score 2):

please try this add in library.json

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ]
```

and in user.json file add these

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },{
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"

    }
  ],
```

u need to give the owner permission for both the models.
Please let me know if you are facing any issue

Comment: Highly unlikely, by default models are not locked.

Comment: thanks it works for me ,but dont know if other user will try to access the same thing it should happen as u have given the "principalId": "$owner",which i dont know what exactly does

Comment: yes correct,@Overdrivr ,so do we give the permission to the user-by-user